# How to color cells with write.xlsx (simple example)

Tags: r, xlsx

I'm writing an R data frame to an .xlsx file.

I'd like certain cells to be filled in with color.  I'm using the `xlsx` package in R, and I'm finding the manual difficult to digest.  Here's a simple example:

```
data(cars)
write.xlsx(cars, "cars.xlsx")
```

Then, I'd like to fill in the cells where `dist` is between 20 and 25, e.g.

Because I simply have a data frame that I directly write using `write.xlsx`, I don't have a workbook java object.

So, I don't think that the examples in `?CellStyle` will work for this case.

I'd love if there is an easy way to, e.g., define a cell style using arguments of `write.xlsx`, or by selecting cells in a data frame (i.e., not in a java object workbook).

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the low level API of xlsx. see the example in the `CellStyle` function.

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet <- createSheet(wb, "Sheet1")
rows  <- createRow(sheet, rowIndex=1)    
cell.1 <- createCell(rows, colIndex=1)[[1,1]]     
setCellValue(cell.1, "Hello R!")
cellStyle1 <- CellStyle(wb) +
    Fill(backgroundColor="orange", foregroundColor="orange",
    pattern="SOLID_FOREGROUND") 
setCellStyle(cell.1, cellStyle1) 
# Then save the workbook 
saveWorkbook(wb, "filename.xlsx")
```

See also the addDataFrame function to add a dataframe and then manipulated cell aspects with the low level API:

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet  <- createSheet(wb, sheetName="your nice sheet name")
addDataFrame(cars, sheet, row.names=FALSE)
# add manipulations here
saveWorkbook(wb, "filename.xlsx")
```

Comment: Excellent -- thanks for this, @Paul4forest.  I've since adopted a non-color based approach, but this is likely to be handy in the future, too.

Comment: Might be because of an update but this code breaks:  > setCellStyle(cell.1, cellStyle1) 
Error in .jcall(cell, "V", "setCellStyle", cellStyle$ref) : 
  object 'cellStyle1' not found